# Executing a php web page (script) inside a loop

Tags: php, curl

Not sure what is the best method to do this.  I want to execute a php script/web page inside a loop passing different parameters.  For example I have an array looking like this:

```
$arr = array(10,11,20,25,31);
foreach($arr as $val){
  //Call php here
  mypage.php?id=".$val."&env=dev;
}
```

Not sure what options I have.  I have tried header, include, file_get_content but they do not do what I need.  Should I be using CURL or maybe execute as a script from command line using exec.
I'm trying to execute the code in the mypage.php page based on the parameter passed in the loop.

Regards
-Martin

Comment: What will calling _mypage.php?id=".$val."&env=dev;_ do?

Comment: "they do not do what I need" ...ok, so what _do_ you need, exactly? It looks like you're trying to call a URL and get the result, so I'd have expected cURL or file_get_contents would work. Did something specific go wrong when you tried them? P.S. Is this PHP file actually part of your own application, or is it another application? Because if it's part of your own application, it would probably make sense to separate whatever logic is in mypage.php that you need, into a separate function which you can call directly, instead of trying to invoke a URL.

Comment: Hi, mypage.php is part of my own application which does a specific task, the page does not return anything.
In short mypage.php uses the parameter value to make an API call to collect data from a remote system. mypage.php is triggered by the remote application by an user action. 
I have a page which collects ID's as part of a cleanup, which needs to be processed by the mypage.php page, hence why I have a loop where I need to execute the mypage.php script passing an ID used for the process in mypage.php.  I need to continuously call the same script with a different parameter each time.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use a jQuery Ajax function to do what I wanted.

```
for(var i in arr){
  id = arr[i];
  url = "https://mypage.php";

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    data: {batchno:id, env:"uat"},
    success: function(str){ }
  });
}
```